# Meta tag duplicate text in a corpus (for word count analysis) in r

Tags: r, corpus, word-frequency

I have a folder with thousands of documents, each one containing a chapter of a book, a letter, or an issue of a periodical. Some of these documents are compilations of other documents, for example one document might contain 10 paragraphs, of which one is original content, 3 are taken from one of the other documents, and 6 from another document, often with elipsis (...) and some of the original content left out.

I want to combine all of this text into one text corpus, for use in word frequency analysis. The challenge I have is that I want any compilation (and thus, duplicate) content to be included only once in the corpus, but ideally with metadata tags for each source document where it appears. So I need a way to remove duplicates (at the sentence or paragraph level, not at the individual word level) but add meta tags for each source document with that same text.

Comment: Please provide some code on what you have tried. Nobody will take your description and write some code. SO is here to help you, if you have a specific problem in concern of programming.

Comment: Ah, good point, I might have to come back later and either update this post or post a new one. At this point, I am looking for an r package or something that can merge duplicates into a corpus, but add meta tags. That is what I came here to ask for, more than the full code on how to do it.